# How to create an application which contains 32bit and 64bit binaries, and runs the appropriate of them on the OS?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

I made an application, and i had to compile a 32bit and a 64bit version of it. I saw some application, like ProcessExplorer acting as follows. On 32bit OS it runs a 32bit app, but on a 64bit OS it extracts a 64bit version of the same exe and this will be executed. So how can i make such an application from my app? What settings should i make in Visual Studio?

Comment: You need to have two binaries. You could have a wrapper program which queries if it is running on Windows 32 or Windows 64, then execute the appropriate program.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes i know that, but if it is possible somehoww, then i would like to have only one executable.

Comment: The only way is to store the 64-bit binary as a resource inside the 32-bit binary. And if it detects 64-bit, copy it out and run it.

Comment: These often get accidentally flagged as viruses, because it is also a convenient way to drop a trojan.  2 binaries and a wrapper where users just use the wrapper is a conservative approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process explorer works like this:

- You download a single 32 bit executable.
- When you run that executable on a 32 bit OS, that's it.
- When you run that executable on a 64 bit OS, the 32 bit process detects that on startup and  to disk extracts a 64 bit executable that is stored as a resource in the 32 bit process. And then it runs that 64 bit executable.

There aren't any settings in Visual Studio that would automate that process for you. You'd have to write that part for yourself. You could have a build process that built the 64 bit version first. And then you could compile that executable into a resource which you link into your 32 bit process. Which is what you ship.

I myself am not convinced it's worth all the effort. Personally I'd be inclined to ship two different executables, but I guess only you know your own requirements.

Comment: Thank you ver much! I tought, this can be through some Visual Studio settings. There isn't any special reason why i wanted to createsuch an app, just thought it would be simplier :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the installation program to install the appropriate version depending on the OS and give that executable the same name for either OS?